# Ember.js - Convert template only display to use a view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, handlebars.js, jquery-masonry

I'm just starting with Ember.js. I've got Ember Data talking to my Rails back end and am currently displaying data with a basic handlebars template. The data is rendering as it should. The current code in coffescript is as follows:

Model:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
  text: DS.attr('string')
  imageUrl: DS.attr('string')
```

Routing:
    App.Router.map ->
      @route 'posts', path: '/'

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.Post.find()
```

posts.handlebars:

```
<div id="masonry-container" class="transitions-enabed infinite-scroll clearfix centered">
  {{#each controller}}
    <div class="col2 box">
     <h3>{{title}}
     <img {{bindAttr src="imageUrl"}} >
     <p class="text">
      {{text}}
     </p>
   </div>
 {{/each}}
</div>
```

application.handlebars

```
{{outlet}}
```

This template is going to be used in several places throughout the application. It also uses masonry which needs to be initialized after the content is rendered, finally I need to implement infinte scrolling, though that's getting a bit ahead of myself.

For now I  would like to to take the above and create a view for it. So far I've tried the following.

Routing:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @route 'posts', path: '/'

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: ->
    @controllerFor('posts').set('content'. App.Content.find())
```

Controller:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend()
```

View:

```
App.PostsView = Ember.View.extend
  layoutName: 'appLayout'
  templateName: 'posts'
  controller: 'App.PostsController'
```

Templates:

app_layout.handlebars

```
...layout mark up...
 <div id="container">
   {{yield}}
 </div>
...more layout mark up...
```

posts.handlebars:

```
<div id="masonry-container" class="transitions-enabed infinite-scroll clearfix centered">
  {{#each controller.content}}
    <div class="col2 box">
     <h3>{{title}}
     <img {{bindAttr src="imageUrl"}} >
     <p class="text">
      {{text}}
     </p>
   </div>
 {{/each}}
</div>
```

application.handlebars

```
{{view App.PostsView}}
```

With this code the layout renders but none of posts do. It seems like the content property of the controller is not getting set, but I'm not sure if I may be missing something else. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. the issue was with calling`{{view App.PostsView}}`. Changing my application.handlebars back to using `{{outlet}}` solved the problem. It seems that trying explicitly render the view was causing problems, and that by defining the view with the correct naming conventions Ember will automatically pick it up. In hind sight this makes a lot of sense considering the Ember way.